# iOS UIView subclass with NIB file does not display the UI designed in IB

Tags: ios, uiview, ios4, interface-builder

I have a class that inherits from UIView, and this class has some controls that I have placed on it in IB.

Then, in the NIB file for my main view controller, I placed a view, and changed the class to my subclass, and created an outlet for the subclass.  However, when I run my application, the app does not display the UI that I put on the subclass, it is just blank.

I am getting the initWithCoder and awakeFromNib messages in the subclass, here is what the subclass .m file basically looks like:

```
#import "AnalyticsDetailView.h"

@implementation AnalyticsDetailView

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    return self;
}

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self)
    {
        NSArray *v = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"AnalyticsDetailView" owner:self options:nil];
        [self addSubview:[v objectAtIndex:0]];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc 
{
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

I am not sure if the initWithFrame is correct, but since that method is not firing, I suspect that it doesn't matter at this point.  If I put a breakpoint in my app after I have seen the subclass methods fire, I can look at the outlet subclass and the frame is the same as what I have created in IB.

Anyone have any suggestions (missing code, bad IB connections, etc.) on what to look for that I have missed or am doing incorrectly?  Thanks.

Comment: why are you doing an InitWithCoder method in a view? Is there some app-specific-data you are archiving/de-archiving?

Comment: also, set a breakpoint in awakeFromNib... if it's not AnalyticsDetailView being loaded, what nib file ***is*** being loaded? initWithFrame will only fire if you explicitly call it from the parent object (when you create the view).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get your interface to appear, you'll need to explicitly instantiate a AnalyticsDetailView from your parent view controller.

So in somewhere like the `viewDidLoad:` or `viewWillAppear:` methods, you'll add a line that says:

```
AnalyticsDetailView * newView = [[AnalyticsDetailView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(x,y,height,width)]; 
[parentView addSubview: newView];
[newView release]; // subview retains for us
```

Comment: My main NIB and view controller class files are way too large as it is, which is why I am trying to create a subclass to move some of the complexity to another location. A couple of things I noticed, I have an InspectView class that logs a view along with all of the subviews, and when using that on the outlet, there are no subviews. Also, there is a view outlet showing up in IB for the subclass, but there is a ! next to it, hovering shows that my class does not have an outlet named view. Also, your previous comment, I'm not sure how to tell which NIB file is being loaded in awakeFromNib.

Comment: okay... I've made a change to my answer. Let me know if this makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for your help Michael, it seems to be working now. I had to jump through some hoops to get the rotation working, but thankfully another SO question had the answer I needed there.